# Problems translating PostgreSQL query to Big Query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, google-bigquery

Hi I'm having trouble translating a PostgreSQL query to BigQuery using the google supplied translation tool. The original PSQL query is

```
create table ld_commonlabs as
  -- extracting the itemids for all the labevents that occur within the time bounds for our cohort
  with labsstay as (
    select l.itemid, la.stay_id
    from labevents as l
    inner join ld_labels as la
      on la.hadm_id = l.hadm_id
    where l.valuenum is not null  -- stick to the numerical data
      -- epoch extracts the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00-00, we want to extract measurements between
      -- admission and the end of the patients' stay
      and (date_part('epoch', l.charttime) - date_part('epoch', la.intime))/(60*60*24) between -1 and la.los),
  -- getting the average number of times each itemid appears in an icustay (filtering only those that are more than 2)
  avg_obs_per_stay as (
    select itemid, avg(count) as avg_obs
    from (select itemid, count(*) from labsstay group by itemid, stay_id) as obs_per_stay
    group by itemid
    having avg(count) > 3)  -- we want the features to have at least 3 values entered for the average patient
  select d.label, count(distinct labsstay.stay_id) as count, a.avg_obs
    from labsstay
    inner join d_labitems as d
      on d.itemid = labsstay.itemid
    inner join avg_obs_per_stay as a
      on a.itemid = labsstay.itemid
    group by d.label, a.avg_obs
    -- only keep data that is present at some point for at least 25% of the patients, this gives us 45 lab features
    having count(distinct labsstay.stay_id) > (select count(distinct stay_id) from ld_labels)*0.25
    order by count desc;
```

My resulting big query sql is :

```
CREATE TABLE mimic_iv.ld_commonlabs
  AS
    WITH labsstay AS (
      SELECT
          --  extracting the itemids for all the labevents that occur within the time bounds for our cohort
          l.itemid,
          la.stay_id
        FROM
          physionet-data.mimiciv_hosp.labevents AS l
          INNER JOIN mimic_iv.ld_labels AS la ON la.hadm_id = l.hadm_id
        WHERE l.valuenum IS NOT NULL
         AND (UNIX_SECONDS(CAST(CAST(l.charttime as DATE) AS TIMESTAMP)) - CAST(UNIX_SECONDS(CAST(CAST(la.intime as DATE) AS TIMESTAMP)) as FLOAT64)) / (60 * 60 * 24) BETWEEN -1 AND la.los
    ), avg_obs_per_stay AS (
      SELECT
          --  stick to the numerical data
          --  epoch extracts the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00-00, we want to extract measurements between
          --  admission and the end of the patients' stay
          --  getting the average number of times each itemid appears in an icustay (filtering only those that are more than 2)
          obs_per_stay.itemid,
          avg(CAST(obs_per_stay.count as BIGNUMERIC)) AS avg_obs
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
                labsstay.itemid,
                count(*) AS count
              FROM
                labsstay
              GROUP BY 1, labsstay.stay_id
          ) AS obs_per_stay
        GROUP BY 1
        HAVING avg(CAST(obs_per_stay.count as BIGNUMERIC)) > 3
    )
    SELECT
        --  we want the features to have at least 3 values entered for the average patient
        d.label,
        count(DISTINCT labsstay.stay_id) AS count,
        a.avg_obs
      FROM
        labsstay
        INNER JOIN physionet-data.mimiciv_hosp.d_labitems AS d ON d.itemid = labsstay.itemid
        INNER JOIN avg_obs_per_stay AS a ON a.itemid = labsstay.itemid
      GROUP BY 1, 3
      HAVING count(DISTINCT labsstay.stay_id) > (
        SELECT
            --  only keep data that is present at some point for at least 25% of the patients, this gives us 45 lab features
            count(DISTINCT labsstay.stay_id) AS count
          FROM
            mimic_iv.ld_labels
      ) * NUMERIC '0.25'
```

However, this is producing the following error

`An expression references labsstay.stay_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [46:28]`

I don't know why it is producing this error. Also the original query is not my query and I'm not great at SQL to begin with so I'm not even sure what it is doing exactly (the goal seems to be to create item ids for lab-events that are then used for time series feats). The broader context is this comes from paper using the MIMIC-IV dataset and the author setup a local PSQL database but now MIMIC-IV is on Big-Query so I'm trying translate it.

Comment: I suggest the original query is almost BigQuery ready, just focus on the datepart line, and get that part working in BigQuery.  The only other thing that might happen is it might complain about numbers/varchar etc and you might have to CAST() some data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your BigQuery SQL query is that the column labsstay.stay_id is being used in the SELECT clause without being either grouped or aggregated. To fix this issue, you should group by labsstay.stay_id as well, in addition to d.label and a.avg_obs:

```
SELECT
    d.label,
    labsstay.stay_id,
    count(DISTINCT labsstay.stay_id) AS count,
    a.avg_obs
FROM
    labsstay
    INNER JOIN physionet-data.mimiciv_hosp.d_labitems AS d ON d.itemid = labsstay.itemid
    INNER JOIN avg_obs_per_stay AS a ON a.itemid = labsstay.itemid
GROUP BY
    d.label, a.avg_obs, labsstay.stay_id
HAVING
    count(DISTINCT labsstay.stay_id) > (
        SELECT
            count(DISTINCT stay_id) AS count
        FROM
            mimic_iv.ld_labels
    ) * 0.25
ORDER BY
    count DESC;
```

This will group the result by d.label, a.avg_obs, and labsstay.stay_id, and return the count of distinct stay_id values along with the other selected columns.

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to help (the query compiled successfully). Though now I have a new problem that the query has been running for over three hours. I'd think that is not normal on BigQuery for it to that long so I don't know what is going on with it.